# Jackson JPA persisting foreign key composite-id fails

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have a JPA entity with a foreign key being part of a composite-id:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CustomerId.class)
public class Customer {

    @Id
    public String id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    public Company company;

}

public class CustomerId  {

    public String id;

    public String company;

}

@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String name;

}
```

and it works. Problem is when I receive a JSON object to be persisted and Jackson unserializes it to a POJO:

```
{
    "id": "Cust0001",
    "company": {
        "id": "Comp1"
     }
}
```

and this the JAX-RS resource:

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void post(Customer customer) {
        em.persist(customer);
    }

}
```

this fails, since JPA (I use Hibernate) tries to cascade `persist` to an unmanaged instance of `Company` with `id` "Comp1", thus throwing a `EntityExistsException`.

The only way I've found to make this work is:

```
customer.company = em.merge(customer.company);
em.persist(customer);
```

but I'm looking for a generalized solution since I have dozens of entities like `Customer` and their JAX-RS resources extend an abstract resource where I don't know what to merge/set before persist the entity.

**UPDATE**

Same problem when try to merge two unserialized objects with a reference to the same entity, e.g.

```
{
    "id": "Cust0001",
    "company": {
        "id": "Comp1"
     },
     relatedCustomer: {
        "id": "Cust9999",
        "company": {
           "id": "Comp1"
        }
     }
}
```

merging this also throws an `EntityExistsException` regarding `Company#Comp1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using `@JsonIdentityInfo` on entity classes, which make Jackson de/serialize objects with no redundancy using identifiers associated with the same instance of each entity.

Answer (score -2):

Hibernate dont support complex query.. please go through hibernate documentation. 
please prefer hql